# Remove item from the list if checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of items with a checkbox, and i have delete button. The delete only works if the item in the list is checked.

So for example i have

```
$scope.list = [{
            name:'Groceries',
            check: false
        }, {
            name:'Laundry',
            check:false
        },
            {
             name:'Cleaning',
             check:false
            }];
```

and in my HTML

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="values in list">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="values.check"/>
      <span>{{values.name}}</span> 
  </li>
</ul>

<button>Delete</button>
```

This is just the snippet of the code i have the controller declared and bootstrapped with ng-app

Comment: So, What is your question?

Comment: @Vinay i want to use the Delete button to remove the items from the display only if they are checked

Answer (score 0):

You should use Angular native directive [`ng-checked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="values.check"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter for this:

HTML

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller='Ctrl'> 
     <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="values in list">
           <input type="checkbox" ng-model="values.check"/>
           <span>{{values.name}}</span> 
        </li>
     </ul>
     <button ng-click="remove((list | filter:{check:true}))">Delete</button>
 </body>
```

Controller

```
$scope.remove = function(items) {
     alert('removing ' + items.length + ' items');
     $scope.list = $filter('filter')($scope.list, { check: false});
}
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLnD7x39LhSiL4GomoDO?p=preview)

Comment: firstly thanks for the response but i want to use the delete button to remove the item from the display. In your case once checking it removes it.

Comment: Updated answer. I hope I've understood what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="MyController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="values in list">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="values.check" />
            <span>{{values.name}}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="deleteItems()">Delete</button>
</body>
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.list = [ {
        name : 'Groceries',
        check : false
    }, {
        name : 'Laundry',
        check : false
    }, {
        name : 'Cleaning',
        check : false
    } ];

    $scope.deleteItems = function() {
        $scope.list = $filter('filter')($scope.list, {check : false})
    }
})
```